# npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"

Tags: npm, artifactory

I tried to run the command:

```
npm install -g @angular/cli@9.1.0
```

but I have got the following error:

> npm ERR! code E401
> npm ERR! Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"
>
> npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
> npm ERR! /Users/xxxx/.npm/_logs/2021-08-10T19_33_12_063Z-debug.log

note: node js and npm worked fine.

I have followed the instructions in Artifactory to solve this issue using the command:

```
npm config set registry https://artifactory.......com/artifactory/api/npm/xxxx/
```

as I have paste the following into the ~/.npmrc file:

```
_auth = fhgf......ghgj==
email = xxx@xxx.com
always-auth = true
```

I have also tried using `npm login`, but I have got the below err and couldn’t continue:

> npm login
> Username: xxx@xxx.com
> npm WARN Name may not contain non-url-safe chars
> Username: (xxx@xxx.com)
> Username: (xxx@xxx.com)
> Username: (xxx@xxx.com)
> Username: (xxx@xxx.com)

How can I solve this issue?

Comment: Can you update the question with how this pertains to the Realm Database?

Comment: Try doing the npm login after adding the registry and try to install?

Comment: I have tried `npm login` I have got the below err and couldn’t continue:

`npm login` 
`Username: xxx@xxx.com` 
`npm WARN Name may not contain non-url-safe chars` 
`Username: (xxx@xxx.com)`

Comment: The npm client doesn't allow email addresses as usernames.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Artifactory moved to support APIKEY only. If your old _auth was base64 encoding of `username:password` or `username:encrypted_password` then both are unacceptable now. You must use APIKEY in place of these.

So, the supported _auth now becomes:

> _auth: APIKEY

But ironically, even this didn't work in some cases.

Following seemed to be more reliable:

1. You need to get base64 string of your username:APIKEY. You can get base64 by running following command in PowerShell

> `[System.Convert]::ToBase64String([Text.Encoding]::UTF8.GetBytes("username:APIKEY"))`

2. Whatever is the output, use that in _auth variable of your .npmrc file (located in `%userprofile%\.npmrc`)

So, the final file looks like following:

```
registry=<URL>
_auth = <Base64 of username:APIKEY>
email = myemail@email.com
always-auth = true
```

Comment: is there a link to the documentation for this change? Im looking now and will post when i find

Comment: Not aware of one. We found out this solution within our team and it seemed to be working for all

Comment: Does this also work with the Identity Token?

Comment: For jFrog Cloud Artifactory, at least, using the combination of `:username` and `:_password` fields still works in place of :_auth.

Answer (score 10):

The issue is due to the '@' special character in the username,  I assume the user is SAML based. Follow the below steps to resolve the issue,

1. Generate the auth token using the /api/npm/auth endpoint with “curl -u :<API_KEY> https://url/artifactory/api/npm/auth/”
2. Add the generated block directly into .npmrc file as

> _auth = Auth-token-generated-from-1st-point

> always-auth = true

Comment: 1. More like: "curl -ujohndoe@company.com:Password url/artifactory/api/npm/auth" where url=http://artifactory.company.com

Comment: this solution worked for me, thank you @Muhammed Kashif - the one which sends the api key

Comment: Here are the Artifactory docs describing how to do this - https://jfrog.com/help/r/jfrog-artifactory-documentation/authenticate-npm-using-basic-authentication

Answer (score 5):

Try something like this.

.npmrc file content like this:

```
//npm.corp_id.com/:_authToken=TOKEN_VALUE_HERE
```

Removing `_` from authToken in .npmrc, It's just for me

```
//npm.corp_id.com/:authToken=TOKEN_VALUE_HERE
```

Comment: Don't know why, but it Just Works™

Comment: This, with adding the `//npm.corp_id.com/:always-auth=true` line, did the job

Answer (score 2):

Login to https://url/artifactory/api/npm/auth/ and copy the _auth value from here to the .npmrc file

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 1):

This issue can also occur when you try to install the package you are publishing as a dependency. I.e. publishing package name @core with a dependency also named @core

Answer (score 1):

vim .npmrc(to edit the configuration file)
i - to insert
`registry=<URL> _auth = <Base64 of username:APIKEY> email = myemail@email.com always-auth = true`

to get the Base64, you can do in your terminal

```
$echo -n cb4b84e9-b861-443c-9ed3-958086d97208 | base64
```

wq - to save document

Answer (score 1):

For me, I already had `.npmrc` file with someone else's expired token. Hence, when i was doing `npm login`, it was giving this authentication error.

To fix this, i deleted the `.npmrc`, executed `npm config set registry ...` command and then `npm login` was executed.

Answer (score 0):

For me, the issue was calling `USER myusername` too early in the Dockerfile, it caused an authentication issue with my artifactory even though the `.npmrc` file was in place.

Simply moving the USER call down, after `npm i` fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

So, two things may be happening here at once:

- Different authentication configuration between npm version ≥v9 and npm version <v9.
- The creation of the `_auth` value.

### Different authentication configuration between npm version ≥v9 and npm version <v9.

---

In [npm v9.0.0](https://github.blog/changelog/2022-10-24-npm-v9-0-0-released/), authentication related settings must be scoped:

**Example**

`.npmrc`

```ini
//<registry>:_auth=<TOKEN>
registry=<registry>
```

That is, you can no longer use `NPM_CONFIG__AUTH` with a raw authentication token:

**Example**

```bash
$ docker run -it docker.io/library/node:14-alpine /bin/sh
/ # npm --version
6.14.18
/ # export NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=***
/ # export NPM_CONFIG__AUTH=***
/ # npm install
...
/ # echo $?
0
```

```bash
$ docker run -it docker.io/library/node:19-alpine /bin/sh
/ # npm --version
9.5.1
/ # export NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY=***
/ # export NPM_CONFIG__AUTH=***
/ # npm install
npm ERR! code E401
npm ERR! Incorrect or missing password.
...
/ # echo $?
1
```

**NOTE**:  `NPM_CONFIG_REGISTRY` is a private npm registry.

(Additional [documentation](https://jfrog.com/knowledge-base/artifactory-changes-to-the-login-behavior-in-npm-v9/) from Artifactory)

Using an `.npmrc` file is backwards compatible with older versions of npm and is the preferred method of authentication configuration.

### The creation of the `_auth` value.

---

Likewise, it would appear in most cases you will need to use an **API Key** in order to authenticate:

```ini
# NOTE: The settings _auth, _authToken, username and _password must all be
# scoped to a specific registry. This ensures that npm will never send
# credentials to the wrong host.
#
# See: https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v8/configuring-npm/npmrc#auth-related-configuration
//<registry>:username=first.last@company.com
# Base64-encoded API Key (***)
//<registry>:_password=***
registry=<registry>
email=first.last@company.com

# A basic-auth string to use when authenticating against the npm registry.
#
#   base64Encode(<username>:<password>)
#
# NOTE: For use with Artifactory, `password` should be an API Key.
//<registry>:_auth=***
```

To create an API Key, click on the user dropdown in the upper-righthand corner, then **Edit Profile**.

Answer (score 0):

I am not a NodeJs / NPM person but tried to figure out what actually happens here for my artifactory set up. These are my findings and it works well in my latest version JFROG artifactory version 7.41.x .

The `_auth` to be added in the *.npmrc* will receive either by:

**1)** Using cURL : `curl -u <username>:<password> -X GET "https://<artifactoryURL>/artifactory/api/npm/auth/"`

**2)** Using base64 encode : Same value can be obtained by generating the base64 value of `base64(<username>:<encrypted-password>)` . The encrypted password can be obtained from the "Edit Profile" section in the UI of that user. I'm not sure where else we can get it.

Artifactory documentation on this is somewhat confusing and I found out this by trial and error.