# Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"

Tags: reactjs, npm, artifactory, vdi, .npmrc

While installing npm I am getting this error

`Unable to authenticate, need: Basic realm="Artifactory Realm"`

I am working on VDI machine, and very new to **artifactory** tool as well as **VDI**, Any advice is appreciated

Thanks :)

Comment: I think it is related to this StackOverflow https://stackoverflow.com/questions/68732744/npm-err-unable-to-authenticate-need-basic-realm-artifactory-realm